bootstrap.min.css panel color not getting displayed
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
the command for downloaded file is not working, the file is unzipped and in the same folder of the html file
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
the CDN method is working
full code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                    block1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                    block2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

I want to use the panel panel-primary and panel panel-success , col-md is working , font is working , only the color isn't being displayed

Downloaded from where, exactly?

getbootstrap.com
